# solr full index issue with records being deleted

Tags: apache, tomcat, solr

I have a simple question, some of you may have already faced this problem.

When I restart tomcat while a full index is in progress I have seen all my records being deleted to 0 records. Is this work as design or is there any flag to disable this behavior.

This in turn affecting my slaves as they all replicate to 0 records.

Example

```
During DIH... 

-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser       20 Nov 28 10:33 segments.gen
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser      253 Nov 28 10:33 segments_3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser  1132805 Nov 28 10:33 _8g.tis
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser    14526 Nov 28 10:33 _8g.tii
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser     4739 Nov 28 10:33 _8g.prx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser     4743 Nov 28 10:33 _8g.nrm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser   676716 Nov 28 10:33 _8g.frq
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser     1472 Nov 28 10:33 _8g.fnm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser    37916 Nov 28 10:33 _8g.fdx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser 11152040 Nov 28 10:33 _8g.fdt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser        0 Nov 28 10:34 write.lock
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser   132932 Nov 28 10:36 _8h.fdx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser 39506829 Nov 28 10:36 _8h.fdt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser  4157436 Nov 28 10:36 _8h.tis
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser    48924 Nov 28 10:36 _8h.tii
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser    16616 Nov 28 10:36 _8h.prx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser    16620 Nov 28 10:36 _8h.nrm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser  2523173 Nov 28 10:36 _8h.frq
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser     1472 Nov 28 10:36 _8h.fnm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser       36 Nov 28 10:36 _8h_1.del
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser        0 Nov 28 10:36 _8i.fdx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser  3227648 Nov 28 10:36 _8i.fdt


After stopping the server


total 69884
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser   132932 Nov 28 10:36 _8h.fdx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser 39506829 Nov 28 10:36 _8h.fdt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser  4157436 Nov 28 10:36 _8h.tis
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser    48924 Nov 28 10:36 _8h.tii
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser    16616 Nov 28 10:36 _8h.prx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser    16620 Nov 28 10:36 _8h.nrm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser  2523173 Nov 28 10:36 _8h.frq
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser     1472 Nov 28 10:36 _8h.fnm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser       36 Nov 28 10:36 _8h_1.del
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser    71892 Nov 28 10:36 _8i.fdx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser 21082644 Nov 28 10:36 _8i.fdt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser        0 Nov 28 10:36 write.lock
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser       20 Nov 28 10:36 segments.gen
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser      474 Nov 28 10:36 segments_4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser        0 Nov 28 10:36 _8j.fdx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser    49152 Nov 28 10:36 _8j.fdt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser  2443628 Nov 28 10:36 _8i.tis
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser    27664 Nov 28 10:36 _8i.tii
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser     8986 Nov 28 10:36 _8i.prx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser     8990 Nov 28 10:36 _8i.nrm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser  1314275 Nov 28 10:36 _8i.frq
-rw-rw-r-- 1 solruser solruser     1472 Nov 28 10:36 _8i.fnm
```

/sr

Comment: Do you already have documents in your core, or is the core empty before you start indexing? Iirc, the index version shouldn't change before an actual commit happens. What do you use for indexing? DIH?

Comment: core is not empty. index version is not changing.  The problem is during DIH if I restart the tomcat accidentally or by purpose I loose all the records in the data/ folder.. it becomes empty.

Comment: If it's a full import, DIH will issue a deleteByQuery with *:* first iirc. This should not do anything if you're not getting a commit as well. Do your Tomcat log show any commits before stopping? Solr still thinks it has a recent index version, but the files are physically missing from the disk?

Comment: I have updated my initial question with an example. but the files are physically missing from the disk? - YES, the old records are all deleted and I do not see any commit in the solr log file.